# Как получить из буфера типа BYTE* 8 байт и перевести их в целочисленный тип?

Tags: c++, c

Здравствуйте у меня есть код в котором есть буфер хранящий данные мне из него нужно по смещению(например 160) получить 8 байт то есть 160:168 и перевести эти байты в целочисленный тип.

```
int main()
{
    int bufferSize = 0; // размер буфера
    BYTE* buffer = GetData(bufferSize); // буфер с данными
    int offset = 160 // смещение с которого начинается нужное значение
}
```

Вопрос как мне это сделать?

Comment: Не указан порядок байт. little-endian, big endian?

Comment: Если порядок байт данных в буфере совпадает с native, то `uint64_t data = *(uint64_t *)(buffer + offset);`

Comment: Пройдитесь в цикле по нужному кусочку буфера и битовыми операциями склейте большое число. `unsigned long long res = 0; for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) res |= (unsigned long long)buffer[offset+i] << i*8;`. Данный способ в отличие от трюка с приведением указателей (`*(uint64_t *)(buffer + offset)`) не чувствителен к порядку байт на целевой машине, не нарушает strict aliasing rule и требования по выравниванию (а такие нарушения стандарта языка вполне [могут привести к проблемам на практике](http://codepad.org/GQ2MaTzy)).

Comment: @wololo, к сожалению, этот способ тоже чувствителен к порядку байт (младший октет числа должен быть в байте с младшим адресом)

Comment: @avp, да, вы правы. В своём комментарии я подразумевал порядок байт в переменной приёмнике `res`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать операцию from\_bytes из python на си?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1441989/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-from-bytes-%d0%b8%d0%b7-python-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b8)

Comment: @avp, ваш способ не сработает на архитектурах, которые не умеют располагать двойные слова по адресу произвольного байта. Есть (были) компьютеры которые умеют читать, например, целые только с адресов кратных четырем. Думаю что единственный надёжный способ - `memcpy` (сборка арифметикой из байтов - отдельная тема).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ну, может быть тем, кому это не очевидно, стоит заняться чем-то другим?