# Как реализовать операцию from_bytes из python на си?

Tags: python, c

Есть такой код на пайтоне

```
count = 10
strt = 20
if count == 10:
    return int.from_bytes(data[strt:strt + 8], "big")
```

Мне нужно сделать тоже самое на си т.е. мне нужно из переменной `data` прочитать 8 байт по смещению `strt` в порядке big-endian но у меня вообще нет идей как это сделать. Я очень хотел бы увидеть реализацию самой функции `from_bytes` на си что-бы понять как она работает.

Comment: Потому что int в python это long

Comment: По второй части ntohl

Comment: Для big-endian д.б. что-то в таком духе `uint64_t from_bytes (const unsigned char data[], int data_len) {  uint64_t res = 0; for (int i = 0; i < data_len; i++) { res <<= 8; /*mpy to 256 */ res |= data[i];} return res;}`

Answer (score 2):

В `C` размер `int` обычно - четыре байта. Для восьми места не хватит.

Функция `from_bytes` читает восемь байт и формирует из них число типа `uint64_t`. Первый байт займёт старшую позицию в числе, последний младшую:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint64_t from_bytes(const uint8_t bytes[/* 8 */]) {
    uint64_t n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        n = (n << 8) | bytes[i];
    }
    return n;
}

int main() {
    uint8_t bytes[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2};
    uint64_t n = from_bytes(bytes);
    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", n);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror temp.c
>
> $ ./a.out
> 258
> ```

Answer (score 0):

я бы советовал вам искать по таким запросам:
from_bytes source code

(source code это базовая реализация функции)
возможно данная ссылка вам поможет
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c